# Get Property guid

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

This is the context: I'm trying to set a bunch of properties to the group "Authenticated Users". For that, I've written the following script:

```
# GETTING AUTHENTICATED USERS SID
$sid1 = "S-1-5-11"
$objSID1 = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($sid1)

# GETTING AUTHENTICATED ACL
$acl = Get-Acl -Path "AD:DC=*****,DC=*****"

# CREATING RULE ATTTIBUTES
$objectGuid = New-Object Guid 5f332e20-9eaa-48e7-b8c4-f4431fef859a 
$identity = [System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference] $objSID1
$adRights = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights] "ReadProperty,WriteProperty"
$type = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType] "Allow"
$inheritanceType = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurityInheritance] "Descendents"
$inheritedobjectguid = New-Object Guid bf967aba-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2

# CREATING THE NEW RULE
$ace = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $identity, $adRights, $type, $objectGuid, $inheritanceType, $inheritedobjectguid

# SETTING THE NEW RULE
$acl.AddAccessRule($ace)
Set-Acl -AclObject $acl "AD:DC=*****,DC=*****"
```

And the final result should be this:

[image: Part One]

[image: Part Two]

One important thing is that what I'm trying to set, as can be seen in the second image, is a **property** and not a **permission**. And that property doesn't have the same GUID in all the computers because I create it with another script before this one.

The question is the following:

In the code where I set `$objectGuid` variable I've hardcoded the GUID I need. What I need to know is if there is any way to get the GUID of the property using PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the GUID of an attribute from the Schema:

1. Query the schemaNamingContext for an `attributeSchema` object
2. Filter on `ldapDisplayName`, the attribute name shown by the GUI
3. Grab the `schemaIDGUID` attribute value and use that in the ACE

I'll use the RSAT `ActiveDirectory` module for simplicity here, but you can do this with any ldap client:

```
$attrSchemaParams = @{
    SearchBase = (Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext
    Filter = "ldapDisplayName -eq 'pwmEventLog' -and objectClass -eq 'attributeSchema'"
    Properties = 'schemaIDGUID'
}
$pwmEventLogSchema = Get-ADObject @attrSchemaParams

$pwmEventLogGUID = $pwmEventLogSchema.schemaIDGuid -as [guid]
```

Now use `$pwmEventLogGUID` in place of `$objectGuid`

Comment: Thank you very much! I've tried something similar but now i realize I was using the ObjectGUID property of the object and that's why it didn't worked before